# How can I fill an existing table with search relevant entries

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I currently have some trouble figuring out on how to "refresh" my table when a user enters a search input.

Right now my page pulls the collection from my MongoDB and then iterates over the array of objects. To this point everything works fine:

```
// Pulls Data from DB
imports: function() {
var importReturn = imports.find({}).fetch();
return importReturn;
}

//Then Iterates over return value and creates an table row for each entry. 
//This #each block is also nested in another template.
{{#each imports}}
  {{> tableRowAdmin}}
{{/each}}
```

Now I added a search bar that until now delivers an object matching to the search entry. But I'm really stuck on how to re-render my template..

```
//The search bar is within a separated template from the table row template 
Template.overviewAdmin.events({
'input .searchInput': function(e){
    var val = event.target.value;
    var object = imports.find(
         {$or:[
    {title: {'$regex': val, $options: 'i' }},
    {"supplier.name": {'$regex': val, $options: 'i'}},
    {"supplier.id": {'$regex': val, $options: 'i'}}
]}
        ).fetch();
    console.log(object);
}
})
```

//CHANGES:

```
//Initializing ReactiveVar in global context
var reactiveQuery = new ReactiveVar({});


//Helper Function:
imports: function() {
var importReturn = imports.find(reactiveQuery.curValue).fetch();
return importReturn;
}

//Event:
'input .searchInput': function(e){
    var val = event.target.value;
    console.log(val);
    reactiveQuery.set(
         {$or:[
    {title: {'$regex': val, $options: 'i' }},
    {"supplier.name": {'$regex': val, $options: 'i'}},
    {"supplier.id": {'$regex': val, $options: 'i'}},
]}
        )
    console.log(reactiveQuery);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual implementation is to take advantage of reactivity.

I guess the very first part of your shown code is a helper? In that case, simply use a `ReactiveVar` instead of `{}` in your `imports.find()`. Of course you can initialize your reactive variable with an empty object.

Then simply update (`set()`) your reactive var with your query string, and reactivity will take care of the rest.

That being said, beware of triggering reactivity too often due to updating on each user input.

---

**Edit** after question rev 2:

What does `reactiveQuery.curValue` gives exactly?

Any reason why not using [`reactiveQuery.get()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html#ReactiveVar-get)?

I believe the reactivity works only when you use the standard `get()` and `set()` methods.

Comment: It's working with the empty object but still not updating when the user enters a search query.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you if you do not provide more details on what you have done in your code. Can you edit / append your question with updated code?

Comment: Just added my changes.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the above answer accordingly.

Comment: The curValue gives after intializing only {} . When I tried to do it without it the reactive Object was more complex.
But where should / could I use the get() method?

Comment: Now I got it! Sorry I really was lost!!!
The get method works. Thanks a lot